# B and I tags should be styled like STRONG and EM on the mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed

The *full* site contains the following CSS:

```
b,strong{font-weight:bold;}i,em{font-style:italic;}
```

But on the *mobile* site, `strong` and `em` are styled, while `b` and `i` are not.  Why does this matter? Because of a long-standing bug, the markdown engine [doesn't handle bold and italics correctly](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/issues-with-bolding) with Japanese, so we often insert HTML tags as a workaround.  But while Markdown turns stars into <em> and <strong>, our community almost always inserts <i> and <b>!

As a result, everything **seems** fine, but if you **look** **at** **the** **mobile** **site**, bold and italics seem to disappear at random.  This can be rather confusing if, for example, [a question or answer refers to the "bolded text"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5530/1478).  (*What* *bolded* *text?*, the reader might ask.)

I've formatted this question to demonstrate the problem; click back and forth between *full site* and *mobile site* to see the difference:

- * *starred italics* - *<i> tag italics*
- ** **starred bold** - **<b> tag bold**

Comment: I'm using iPad chrome browser, both \* and <i> are rendered as bolded italic text, making them undistinguishable from \*\*\*.

Comment: It's not the *browser*, but the version of the site you're looking at.  Click the **mobile** link at the bottom of the page to view the mobile version of the site.  Click **full site** at the bottom to return to normal.

Comment: wow, I didn't know there's a mobile site. Tag i and b disappear completely. \* still looks like \*\*\*, which might be my browser's problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this was a more general problem affecting SE sites other than Japanese, after six months had passed I posted [a bug report on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230881/i-and-b-tags-should-be-styled-like-em-and-strong-on-mobile-beta-site-css).

Soon after, the bug was fixed.